# Does creating an object from another injected object break dependency injection?

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I have a class that uses a `pyodbc` database connection, the class also uses the `cursor` of that connection to execute sql statements, so currently I inject the database connection like so:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db
        self.cursor = db.cursor()
```

Although I'm questioning if I am not adhering to proper dependency injection by using `self.cursor = db.cursor()`. Should I instead inject the cursor too? Like so:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, db, cursor):
        self.db = db
        self.cursor = cursor
```

Another thought I had was to not have a `self.cursor` instance variable, and to just call `self.db.cursor()` any time I need to use the cursor.

What is the best approach in order to have a class that properly injects its dependencies? Does the class depend on the database connection **and** the cursor, or **just** the database connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say that I know the best approach, but a surefire way would be to simply keep the cursor as a property of your class;

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db

    @property
    def cursor(self):
        return self.db.cursor()
```

This will allow you to use classobj.cursor as you would have wanted to originally, while keeping it tied to the db object.